# Connect to database made in XAMPP via C#

Tags: c#, sql, xampp

I have local server for my site (i made it with XAMPP). How can i connect from C# to my database made in XAMPP? I have global ip and everyone can access to my page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem with Mysql connector.